# How to Have Datalist Header on Left Side Only

Tags: c#, datalist, html-table

I have a  datalist which displays data in three columns.Each column represent one set of result. So i need to have header on left, so that it will look like following:

```
**plan**                   HMO       PPO      Indem
**Vendor Name**            vendor1  vendor2   vendor3
```

And so on. I am able to get the data displayed properly into three columns, but i don't know how to get the  header on left. Currently I am using separate table next to datalist on the left to display the header name for each row with fixed height. But there is one problem,  If my content of one of cells data in datalist is bigger than expected then alignment is messed up.Please suggest me the best way.

This is a problem especially in cross-browser testing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:

```
$(".tableRight tr").each(function(i) {
    $("..tableLeft tr").eq(i).height($(this).height());
});
```